# Prove that the coefficient of friction has to be $ μ >3/2\frac {sin \theta}{1+3sin^2 \theta}$ for pure rolling of an inclined rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

A rod of mass $M$, and length $L$ is kept at an angle $\theta$ on a surface (at rest), and then released.
Prove that the coefficient of friction has to be $ μ >3/2 \frac {sin \theta}{1+3sin^2 \theta}$

The condition is that there is no slipping, and only pure rolling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51367/discussion-between-mathjack-and-harsha-g).

Comment: Per [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583), this clearly qualifies as a homework-like question. It is just a request for a proof/calculation with no effort and no physical context shown.

Comment: This is not the right forum for what you seek. Read any relevant book of mechanics. Search in google. See youtube. Show some effort please.